# Will starting a new game under a new user delete the data from the main user?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Will starting a new game under a new user delete the data from the main user?

Comment: If I have answered your question please mark it as answered, otherwise please elaborate further.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, since you are using a PS3, the answer is no. If you are signed in to your profile, let's call is `Steve` and the other user is `Bob`, then being signed in as `Steve` won't affect `Bob`'s save file information at all.